# How do I install a panel fence on an angle to a fence post?

Tags: woodworking, fence, carpentry

For reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIIuhlcqSE0&t=292s

If you see how they install the panels to the fence posts, they are using some brackets on the fence post that they slide the panel's railings into. So this would only work for 90 degree angle fence walls. How do I attach panels to fence posts at an angle, like say at 30 degrees?

Comment: 30 Dgr witch way. Vertical board to post is 30 Dgr. make simple drawing or take picture.

Answer (score 1):

It is not 90 dgr, it is actually 180 Dgr in reference to previous fence not to the fence post.

90 Dgr would be a corner of the fence. 90 is easy, just nail the brackets on the 90 dgr side of the post from othe original fence.

So your 30 Dgr could be going inward (180-30)

or going outward 180+30.

Either way, take a 2x4 and cut a ~30 dgr angle with table saw.

Nail it to the post and now nail the brackets to it on the sloped side.